# Regular expression replace (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

How to make Regex.Replace for the following texts:

```
1) "Name's",     "Sex", "Age", "Height_(in)", "Weight (lbs)"
2) " LatD", "LatM ", 'LatS', "NS", "LonD", "LonM", "LonS", "EW", "City", "State"
```

Result:

```
1) Name's, Sex, Age, Height (in), Weight (lbs)
2) LatD, LatM, LatS, NS, LonD, LonM, LonS, EW, City, State
```

Spaces between brackets can be **any size** (Example 1). There may also be **incorrect spaces** in brackets (Example 2). Also, instead of spaces, the **"_"** sign can be used (Example 1). And instead of double quotes, single quotes can be used (Example 2).

**As a result, words must be separated with a comma and a space.**

*Snippet of my code*

```
StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(...);
var fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
fileRow = Regex.Replace(fileRow, "_", " ");
fileRow = Regex.Replace(fileRow, "\"", "");
var fileDataField = fileRow.Split(',');
```

Comment: Yes, I don't know much about regular expression...

Comment: Not to do with the question, but it's `Names` - no apostrophe.

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Comment: [Is that](https://regex101.com/r/kHLXR2/1) what you want?

Comment: Probably, `fileRow = Regex.Replace(fileRow, @"(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')(?:(,)(\s)*|\s*$)", m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()}{m.Groups[2].Value.Trim()}{m.Groups[3].Value}{m.Groups[4].Value}")`

Comment: @Toto missed Height_(in), Yes, what you need) And how to insert it into the code?

Comment: [Updated](https://regex101.com/r/kHLXR2/2)

Comment: @Toto Make out your answer with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't well know C# syntax, but this regex does the job:

- Find: `(?:_|^["']\h*|\h*["']$|\h*["']\h*,\h*["']\h*)`
- Replace: `A space`

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # non capture group
    _                       # undersscore
  |                         # OR
    ^["']\h*                # beginning of line, quote or apostrophe, 0 or more horizontal spaces
  |                         # OR
    \h*["']$                # 0 or more horizontal spaces, quote or apostrophe, end of line
  |                         # OR
    \h*["']\h*              # 0 or more horizontal spaces, quote or apostrophe, 0 or more horizontal spaces
    ,                       #
    \h*["']\h*              # 0 or more horizontal spaces, quote or apostrophe, 0 or more horizontal spaces
)                           # end group
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kHLXR2/2/)

Comment: \h - [[:blank:]], ok)

Comment: @MiT: OK, thank you, may be `\s` can be used instead of `\h`

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple straight string manipulation way?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dirty1 = "\"Name's\",     \"Sex\", \"Age\", \"Height_(in)\", \"Weight (lbs)\"";
    string dirty2 = "\" LatD\", \"LatM \", 'LatS', \"NS\", \"LonD\", \"LonM\", \"LonS\", \"EW\", \"City\", \"State\"";
    Console.WriteLine(Clean(dirty1));
    Console.WriteLine(Clean(dirty2));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string Clean(string dirty)
{
    return dirty.Split(',').Select(item => item.Trim(' ', '"', '\'')).Aggregate((a, b) => string.Join(", ", a, b));
}

private static string CleanNoLinQ(string dirty)
{
    string[] items = dirty.Split(',');
    for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i] = items[i].Trim(' ', '"', '\'');
    }
    return String.Join(", ", items);
}
```

You can even replace the LinQ with a foreach and then string.Join().

Easier to understand - easier to maintain.